# Anyway for extracting pure Month name (converting numbers of month to str month) using pandas for the column inline and adding a new column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I tried these codes but I could not get any result. would be thankful if you could help

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['05-01-2018', '02-20-2020']})

df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df['Month'] = df['Date'].dt.month
df['Month-str'] = df['Date'].dt.strftime('%b')
df['Month-str-full'] = df['Date'].dt.strftime('%B')

 print(df)



from datetime import datetime
a=df['Release Date'].sort_values()
# a = datetime(2017, 11, 28, 23, 55, 59, 342380)
print("year =", a.year)
print("month =", a.month)
 none of codes above worked.
```

Comment: your code seems to work fine for me (at least the datetime strftime part), what exactly is the issue?

Comment: Yes, you're totally right, but the point of mine which made me fall into trap was not casting that 'specific column'  into the datetime type object and not manipulating with the right data; therefore I was out of shot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
In [845]: df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

In [847]: df['Mon_name'] = df['Date'].dt.strftime('%b')                                                                                                                                                     

In [848]: df                                                                                                                                                                                                
Out[848]: 
        Date Mon_name
0 2018-05-01      May
1 2020-02-20      Feb
```

**OR full month names like this:**

```
In [849]: df['Mon_name'] = df['Date'].dt.strftime('%B')                                                                                                                                                     

In [850]: df                                                                                                                                                                                                
Out[850]: 
        Date  Mon_name
0 2018-05-01       May
1 2020-02-20  February
```

Comment: Completely Solved it. Thanks a lot